# Insert rows in a protected worksheet in excel 2010

Tags: vba, excel

I want to insert rows in a protected worksheet.  I am using the following code in ThisWorkbook code window, but it is not working.  Can someone please help me?

```
Private Sub workbook_Open()

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Protect Password:="vba2014", UserInterFaceOnly:=True, AllowInsertingRows:=True
        .EnableOutlining = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It works for me in 2010 - what error do you get?

Comment: I am not getting any error, but unable to insert rows

Comment: I am also using excel 2010, still I am unable to insert rows

Comment: Are you inserting the rows programmatically or manually'

Comment: Is Excel in compatibility mode for older versions of Excel? If the worksheet was originally from Excel 97-2003 then Excel will be in compatibility mode and that feature will not work.

Comment: I am inserting manually

Comment: No. It is not in compatibility mode.  This was created in excel 2010 only.

Comment: Works for me. Two Dumb Questions: `1` Where is "workbook_Open" code placed. Since the "W" is small in "workbook_Open", I am assuming that you have pasted the code in the wrong place. `2` Are macros enabled? Maybe the workbook is previously protected and the code doesn't even run and hence you are unable to insert the code?

Comment: Are you able to select a row?

Comment: Hi Siddharth Rout,  Code is placed in "Thisworkbook" code window.  After placing the code, I have protected the workbook.  I am also having some other code in worksheet change which is working very fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UserInterFaceOnly:=True` parameter in `Worksheet.Protect` serves to

> protect the user interface, but not macros. If this argument is omitted, protection applies both to macros and to the user interface.

That is to say, it allows macros to run on a protected sheet but users are still restricted to doing things allowed within protection settings

You could try setting `AllowInsertingRows:=True` when applying worksheet protection but this approach isn't always effective e.g. if you have tables/list objects or merged cells on the sheet.

Comment: I tried, but still it is not working.  I am unable to find out the reason behind this :(